# Rails - destroy a 'join table' association where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I wonder if there is a rails way to destroy a has_many association, given a condition.
**buyer**

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Telephone'
end
```

**telephone**

```
class Telephone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phoneable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I want to join Buyers with Telephones and destroy all telephones `where('buyers.tel = telephones.number')`. What's the best way to write this query?

Comment: If the tables do not currently exist, I would suggest creating a migration to create the joined table. Then write a rake task to populate it.

Answer (score 1):

if you to handle that for only 1 `Buyer` record:

```
buyer = Buyer.first
buyer.phones.where('number = ?', buyer.tel).destroy_all
```

if for all `Buyers`:

```
# XXX this will select all buyers you want but in your case you want to destroy the phones not the buyers so we need the reverse one check next:
Buyer.joins(:phones).where("buyers.tel = telephones.number")

# but this one will as we need the reverse relation:
Telephone.where("phoneable_type = 'Buyer' and buyers.tel = telephones.number").includes(:phoneable)
```

Note we add a condition that `phoneable_type = 'Buyer'` as you have a polymorphic relation and you you only need the one which created for `Buyer` only

Comment: This means I have to run a query for each record in Buyers. Is there a way to do it in a single join query?

Comment: @leemour check the updated answer for work with 1 Buyer and work with all Bueyrs